# While-loop inside function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, while-loop

I'm working on a project about excess of loss reinsurance pricing, so I defined two functions: the first one computes cost retained by the insurer:

```
charge_assureur=[]
def CHARGE(c,d):
    for i in range(0, len(ma_base)):
        if ma_base.iloc[i,2] < d:
            charge_assureur.append(ma_base.iloc[i,2])
        elif ma_base.iloc[i,2] > c:
            charge_assureur.append(ma_base.iloc[i,2]-c)
        else :
            charge_assureur.append(d)
    return(charge_assureur)
```

Where `ma_base` is a `dataframe` with 827 rows and 30 columns (the second column contains costs, so the output is a list with length=827).
Then I define another function which contains while loop and calls the first function, it is a sort of binary-search algorithm which looks for the maximum priority chosen by the insurer.

```
Portee=10**12
MAX=2*10**7
lengths=[39,125,67,72,88,65,18,93,125,72]


def Priorite_maximale_dichotomie():
    b=max(sinistre.montant[sinistre.montant>=u])
    a=0
    while (b-a)>1 :
        Priorite=(a+b)/2
        if np.quantile(CHARGE(Portee,Priorite )), .95) > MAX:
            b=Priorite
        else :
            a=Priorite
    return(Priorite)
```

My problem is that when function `CHARGE` is called in function `Priorite_maximale_dichotomie`, it returns a list with length=1654 in the second iteration, 2481 in third one...and so on.
Could someone help me fix this problem, please? By calling the function `CHARGE` in the second function, I want to have a list with length 827 for each possible couple `(Porte, Priorite)`.

Comment: Define `charge_assureur` as a local variable inside the CHARGE function, instead of a global variable.

Comment: Every time you call `CHARGE()` it appends to the `charge_assureur` list, without emptying it first. So the list just gets longer and longer.